# Report data is not displayed - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, reporting

I have just started to make report in wpf, but getting following error

```
An error occurred during local report processing. The report definition for report 'Project Path' has not been specified. Could not nto fild file 'File Path'
```

here is my code

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Model.TruckDriver> truckDriver   = BLL.TruckDriver.GetTruckDriversList(2);
        ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";

        ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("ReportViewer_Driver", truckDriver);
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
        reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        windowsFormsHost1.Child = reportViewer;
    }
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in the output directory is no file *Report1.rdlc*? If you compile in debug mode, it must be in the *bin/debug*-directory, in release it must be in *bin/release*.

If this is the problem, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702088/getting-the-relative-path-to-the-rdlc-report-in-my-winform-app) post. Probably it will help.

Comment: Thanks... well picked.. now I have set like this reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../../Report1.rdlc";